# How do I download a file in Watir?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I'm starting to use Watir and I can't find anything about downloading a file (not an image, I've seen there's a specific method for that) and I don't care about configuring the download directory, nor where a button is clicked, just when I'm on a page, be it .html, .png, .rb how am I supposed to "Save as"? This really isn't made clear

I can right click on a link to a page but can't send_keys :down (it just moves the page down in the background of the right click context menu) as follows:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto "https://github.com/lmmx/watir-paper-scanner/blob/master/bookworm.rb"
browser.a(:text => "Raw").right_click
```

**Edit:** just put in the above code used to get an example of what I was actually trying to do as a little test, the last bit. `.right_click` works but `.send_keys` doesn't act on the context menu it produces, it moves the page instead, this could be substituted for some sort of .download function if there is one

What am I missing here...?

Comment: Can you provide (the minimum amount of) sample HTML to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm not really asking for a specific problem... I was on Github and had to download my code for the project I was working on and rather than right clicking [Raw](https://raw.github.com/lmmx/watir-paper-scanner/master/bookworm.rb) > 'Save as' I thought, hmm I'm sure I can get Watir to do this, and since I'm already in a Ruby shell using it why not give it a go... but then I Googled around and no sign of any way to download something using Watir. I can't really produce sample HTML when what I'm asking for is a thing-I-don't-know-how-to-do if you get me? Sorry :(

Comment: I'll edit the second paragraph to include the code for that, but like I say it's an incorrect method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the 'context menu' that is opening up actually a operating system level 'file finder' dialog?  if so that is outside of the DOM and nothing based on webdriver is going to be able to touch it.  at that point you are talking to the OS, not the browser.  The browser has basically told the OS 'hey ask the user to pick a file and return the file path to me' and you the user are no longer interacting with the browser.

proof of this would be to right click on something in the dialog, if you do not see an 'examine element' option, you are very likely not in the browser.

at that point, look into something like RAutomation or AutoIt

Comment: Thanks Chuck, I'm not using Watir for my project after all but was just trying this out. If I get chance I'll take another look, appreciate the advice :)

Comment: that would apply pretty much no matter what browser driver you are using, especially for the large number of them that are based on webdriver.